# HP 7600DC XP BSOD

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bios, bsod

BACKGROUND

- HP DC7600 Desktop circa 2005: received in 2012
- Symptoms are new and have not been observed before
- Symptoms observed with 2 different SATA disks
- Boot from USB stick fail: boots from HDD
- Fails to boot with sysrescueCD 0.3.5. =>  Blinking Keyboard: Caps and Scroll Lock LEDs

Screenshot:

[image]

SYMPTOMS

[image]

BIOS SETTINGS

Because the BIOS settings have not been problematic in the last 3 years I do not think they are the problem, however, if they are a problem:

[image]

QUESTIONS \ REQUESTS

1. Are there any other additional test / diagnostics to determine root
   cause of problem?
2. If you have seen / solved this problem please indicate this in your
   response
3. If your diagnosis is mapped to corrective action already posted, a
   link is appreciated.
4. What does not being ACPI compliant actually mean: how do I verify
   compliance?

It's odd that after 3 years the machine is seemingly out of nowhere 'not ACPI compliant'

BIOS UPGRADE ATTEMPT

Despite the indication of success, attempt to upload the image via BIOS and CD is not good: no BIOS image on monitor.  I am not sure how one would try to do this again without a good working BIOS.

[image]

[*Link to Website for BIOS*](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=499678&swItemId=ir_73174_2&swEnvOid=1093)

Comment: Have you tried enabling ACPI S3 Hard Disk Reset?  Have you tried updating the BIOS?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Good questions: Yes: attempt to enable ACPI S3 results in the same symptoms. Attempt to Flash ROM seemed successful (see photo above), however booting up the machine: no BIOS observed on monitor.   @downvoter: If voting down a post, that's fine: leave some constructive feedback.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560114(v=vs.85).aspx  here is the issue: **If Parameter 1 equals 0x11, the system could not enter ACPI mode.** parameter 2 = 0x7 which is checksum error: **A pointer to the table that had a bad checksum**

Answer (score 0):

[Despite a shaky start upgrading the BIOS,](https://superuser.com/questions/1112502/hp-dc7600-bios-upgrade-failure) it seems that the problem is resolved.  It is a little puzzling that XP did not complain about the BIOS for years and suddenly the BIOS is unfit.  Wondering now if BIOS was somehow corrupted and how to prevent corruption.

[BIOS Upgrade Link](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=499678&swItemId=ir_73174_2&swEnvOid=1093): the download must be unzipped on Windows box and the .iso file can be burned to a CD and presented to the current BIOS for install.