# HP dc7600 BIOS Upgrade Failure

Tags: boot, bios

## BACKGROUND

PC was built by HP in 2005: acquired PC in 2012.  After 3 years of use, Windows indicates a problem with the BIOS and the machine is unable to boot with a linux rescueCD.

Attempts to upgrade the BIOS indicate success, however, the machine does not seem to boot the BIOS.  Monitor indicates no signal

- [HP DC7600 Technical Reference Manuals](https://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.sn=2ua6120s9b&sp4ts.oid=472276&docId=emr_na-c00368802&sp4ts.pn=EH799UC&docLocale=en_US)
- [HP DC7600 List of Documentation \ Manuals](https://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/manualsResults/?sp4ts.oid=472276&sp4ts.sn=2ua6120s9b&sp4ts.pn=EH799UC&spf_p.tpst=psiContentResults&spf_p.prp_psiContentResults=wsrp-navigationalState%3Daction%253Dmanualslist%257Cviewall%253Dtrue%257Clang%253Den&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)
- [Link to HP DC7600 BIOS](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=499678&swItemId=ir_73174_2&swEnvOid=1093)

## QUESTIONS:

1. If the BIOS is foobar, what can be done to correct or re-install?
2. What diagnostic can be performed?
3. Procedures / actionable suggestions are appreciated.

## BIOS Configuration Info

[image: BIOS Configuration Info]

[image: Success Indicator]

Comment: Disconnect AC and remove main battery, if you can remove cmos battery, wait 15 min, reinsert cmos battery and connect AC power, power up, if you get a bios screen enter bios immediately and set date and time.

Comment: Also see this document..http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04126730

Comment: Also this one...http://www.systutorials.com/3022/hp-compaq-bios-crisis-recovery-from-a-failed-bios-flashing/

Comment: Adding to @Moab said, unplug ALL cables and hold down the power button for 45 seconds or so to "drain the capacitors."

Comment: Also, do have more than one video output?  If so, try using the embedded VGA  output only.

Comment: @Moab: if you copy your first response into an answer, I will grant you credit.  rjt:I had a second video card and tested both video ports: no activity.  I bounced the CMOS battery (per Moab) and removed the second video card.  Disconnected all cables and spent 15 minutes blowing out dust \ discharging capacitors. System is now working: Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disconnect AC and remove main battery, if you can remove cmos battery, wait 15 min, reinsert cmos battery and connect AC power, power up, if you get a bios screen enter bios immediately and set date and time.